# codeigniter not equal query error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i do not equal in my query in mysql database to codeigniter framework. My query shows not equal to the position of admin. Here is my query

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_user_type.position, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname,
                    tbl_users.user_mname FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_user_type ON tbl_users.user_type = tbl_user_type.user_type 
                    WHERE !(tbl_user_type.position = Admin) ');
        return $query->result();
```

Comment: If you store the position as a string in the database, you need to quote it: `tbl_user_type.position != "Admin"`

Comment: I can't understand why you are not using active-records for such a simple query? It is more simpler using active records...

Answer (score 1):

Please use active records query to do this task, it will be more simple with active records in codeigniter.

```
$this->db->select("UT.position, U.user_id, U.user_fname, U.user_lname, U.user_mname");
$this->db->from("tbl_users AS U");
$this->db->join("tbl_user_type AS UT", "U.user_type = UT.user_type"); 
$this->db->where("UT.position !=", "Admin");
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
```

Replace your query with above code. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try following one.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_user_type.position, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname,
                tbl_users.user_mname FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_user_type ON tbl_users.user_type = tbl_user_type.user_type 
                WHERE tbl_user_type.position != "Admin" ');
    return $query->result();
```

OR

```
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_user_type.position, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname,
                tbl_users.user_mname FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_user_type ON tbl_users.user_type = tbl_user_type.user_type 
                WHERE tbl_user_type.position <> "Admin" ');
    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
$this->db->where('tbl_user_type.position !=','Admin');
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_user_type.position, tbl_users.user_id, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname,
                    tbl_users.user_mname FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_user_type ON tbl_users.user_type = tbl_user_type.user_type');
 return $query->result();
```